# How to disable a RadioGroup until checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-group

I have a radio group which I do not want to user to be able to select any of the buttons until a particular checkbox is selected within my app. If the checkbox is unticked then this disables the radio-group. How do I go about doing this.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The real trick is to loop through all children view (in this case: `CheckBox`) and call it's `setEnabled(boolean)`

Something like this should do the trick:

```
//initialize the controls
final RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

//set setOnCheckedChangeListener()
ck1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton checkBox, boolean checked) {
        //basically, since we will set enabled state to whatever state the checkbox is
        //therefore, we will only have to setEnabled(checked)
        for(int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++){
            ((RadioButton)rg1.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(checked);
        }
    }
});

//set default to false
for(int i = 0; i < rg1.getChildCount(); i++){
    ((RadioButton)rg1.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: It is nice to know that the "dirty hack" I did seems to be the actual way of doing it. :D

Comment: Setting enabled as false hides the radio button's "radio". It results in a very bad UX. I agree with the setClickable(false) in Kishita's answer.

Comment: You can change `setEnabled` within the loop to `setClickable` as you see fit. The algorithm will still work either way.

Answer (score 11):

If you have just a few radio buttons, better way would be to setClickable(false) for all children

```
radiobutton1.setClickable(false);
radiobutton2.setClickable(false);
radiobutton3.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 9):

RadioGroup cannot be disabled directly, we have to loop through the radio button and setEnabled as false.

```
// To disable the Radio Buttons of radio group.
    for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        radioUser.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: What should be "radioUser" variable if the for loop is dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement the same for Kotlin, Here's my code->
where rgNotificationType is the radio group name.

```
for (i in 0 until rgNotificationType.childCount) {
        (rgNotificationType.getChildAt(i)).isEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

By using kolin's extensions:

```
fun RadioGroup.setChildrenEnable(enable: Boolean) {
    for (i in 0 until this.childCount) {
        this.getChildAt(i).isEnabled = enable
    }
}
```

And in your code you can just call the function like this:

```
radioGroup.setChildrenEnable(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [onCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) on your CheckBox and use the method [setEnabled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29) on your RadioGroup.

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work on RadioGroup. It does not propagate down it seems.

Answer (score -1):

**Kotlin Solution**

```
for (index in 0..radio.childCount - 1)
    radio.getChildAt(index).isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score -3):

Take actions according to the state of the checkbox and set the radiogroup accordingly. 
Assuming that you have a radio-group named radiogroup you can enable or disable the radiogroup by

radiogroup.setEnabled(true);

Add a OnCheckedChangeListener() to your checkbox.

Comment: Individual RadioButton items have to be disabled.