# I'm interested in how to disable to change to click on another radiobutton?

Tags: java, android

How to disable radio buttons group after clicking on some radio button in Android activity ?

This is my XML code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tPitanje1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Neposredno regulisanje saobracaja na putevima vrse:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tPitanje1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="uniformisani komunalni policajci" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unoformisani policijski sluzbenici" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="inspektori za drumski saobracaj" />
    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Java Code

```
   package com.example.autoskola;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class obs1 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.obs1);
    }

}
```

**I'm interested in how to disable to change to click on another radiobutton?**

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your last sentence but it sounds like you want to disable a group after a user checks a button. If so, are you sure you want to do this? What if they accidentally pick the wrong one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to disable the `RadioGroup` once a certain `RadioButton` is clicked. Just add an `OnCheckedChangedListener` and if the id of the `RadioButton` clicked is the right one, then disable the group by using `setEnabled(false)`. Of course, you can't reenable the `RadioGroup` unless you have some other logic in your code that will do the re-enabling.

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById (R.id.radioGroup1);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangedListener (new OnCheckedChangedListener(){
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
{
  if (checkedId == R.id.radio0)
    group.setEnabled(false);
}
});
```

Edit: It seems that `setEnabled()` doesn't work, so you should try changing your code so it [loops through each `RadioButton`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377769/1815485) upon checking `radio0`:

```
if (checkedId == R.id.radio0){
   for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++){
            ((RadioButton)rg1.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, when  I looked at it was logical that the workbut when I tried to use this in my code showed that they can still change the value in RadioGroup.

Comment: @Muskolo so you mean the RadioGroup is not being disabled?

Comment: Yes RadioGroup is not disabled it still can change RaddioButton i also try isClickable but no effects.

Comment: @Muskolo Seems `setEnabled()` doesn't work, you should loop through the children like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9377769/1815485) answer.